# Why is MATLAB definition of complex dot product the complex conjugate of the common definition?

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, dot-product

Let's assume we want to multiply two **complex** column vectors `A` and `B`, i.e. take the dot product.
We can do this with `A'*B` or `dot(A, B)`.

However, the [MATLAB docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) states that

[image: matlab definition]

While [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors) states that

[image: wikipedia definition]

Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Presumably wikipedia is wrong. Matlab's interpretation seems consistent over octave, julia, and python. Having said that, this seems to be a question of mathematical convention rather than of correctness; the two answers are related in that one is the complex conjugate of the other. At the very least wikipedia (and matlab) should have had a citation for favouring that convention over the other. Perhaps it's worth asking this in mathsexchange instead.

Comment: Note that both definitions are justified by the same resulting properties of the dot product.

Comment: This is likely convention.  It seems to be the case that physicists typically use the definition consistent with MATLAB, whilst standard linear algebra books define the inner product that is consistent with the Wiki.

Comment: This has been discussed in math exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535786/235399

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked to the developers of MATLAB and/or requires references on both Wikipedia and the MATLAB one.

Comment: @Metahominid I strongly disagree with you. Multiplication is commutative, that's right. However, it does matter which factor is conjugated. As Tasos noted, the results of both definitions are the complex cojugate of each other.

Comment: @Metahominid Please stop stating that there is no difference in the computation. **The two results are not equal**. As stated in *both* of the links provided, `dot(u,v) == conjugate(dot(v,u))`. Yes, multiplication is commutative but no, the dot product of complex vectors is not.

Comment: Im saying the computational time is the same. It's like arguing over who has the best hand writing. Go look in the python ref and youll see it is different but you get the same result.

Comment: Also note it actually says that at the bottom of the reference page of the dot product for matlabs dot product.